# What is a difference between setOnItemClickListener() and setOnGroupClickListener() for an Expandable ListView?

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I tried **setOnItemClickListener()** for an Expandable `ListView` but it didn't work as I expected! Is there any difference in operation for **setOnItemClickListener()** and **setOnGroupClickListener()** for an Expandable `ListView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something happen when you select a Group header use `setOnGroupClickListener()`

If you want something to be happen when an child item is clicked (of a certain group) use `setOnChildClickListener()`

`setOnItemClickListener()` isn't much of a use in case of `ExpandableListView`

Comment: Thanks for solving the confusion.